# Get updated keys from mybatis mapper xml

Tags: sql, mybatis

Following is my query which will update TableA based on condition X.

```
UPDATE
TableA 
SET columnA = value
WHERE columnB > 5;
```

Will it be possible to return the updated rows' primaryKey as a List in the mapper xml.

Answer (score 1):

you can use "returning tableA.primaryKey into X" in the update statement and have a result parameter in your mapper.

Comment: Will you be able to provide example for this with preferred keywords?